# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strftime' in Python

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I have the following data:

```
costs_for_roi.index.values
array(['2017-03-05T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-03-12T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-03-19T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-03-26T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-04-02T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-04-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-04-16T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-04-23T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns])
```

and need to run this piece of code:

```
costs_for_roi
datelist = list(costs_for_roi.index.values).strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S")
datelist
```

but i keep getting the aformentioned error

is this due to the wrong fortmatting, or some module that is missing ?

Comment: @Jay i am getting "numpy.datetime64' object has no attribute 'strftime'" with the proposed snippet

Comment: Try `datelist = [x.astype('datetime64[s]').item().strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S") for x in list(data)]`

Comment: i guess you meant datelist = [x.astype('datetime64[s]').item().strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S") for x in list(costs_for_roi.index.values)]. It works, thank!

Answer (score 0):

Just try

> datelist = list(costs_for_roi.index.strftime("%Y-%m-%dTTT%H:%M:%S"))

It seems that your work with `pd.DataFrame` object. `DatetimeIndex` has built-in method `strftime`

When you do `list(costs_for_roi.index.values)`, you create new object `List<numpy.datetime64>`. Neither `list` or `numpy.datetime64` don't have `strftime` method